# Formula for simple interest calculation but with added base fee

Tags: algebra-precalculus, finance, interpolation

I have a situation where I need to offer third parties an installment plan for paying back a debt. This installment plan has an 8% yearly rate, but with some strict rules.

The situation has 3 interesting values:

- The principal where we can add an 8% yearly rate (but not compound)
- Existing fees which are static (no yearly rates)
- Existing interest calculated

The payment priority is first interest, then fees and in the end, principal.

So in practice, let's say the debtor owes 1.000 USD (principal), 400 USD (fees) and 100 USD (existing interest). The debtor now agrees to a 12-month payment plan. The key is the debtor agrees to a time-period with the same installment every month.

The first couple of months would be only "interest + fees". When fees are paid, "interest + principal". As the principal goes down, the less monthly interest.

**MY QUESTION:**

I found it pretty easy to make the calculations by selecting a monthly installment. But switching it around and when my input is "months" - and I try to find the monthly installment I get lost.

What formula should I use here?

Comment: It seems a bit confusing... What is "existing interest"? How is calculated the interest on the principal? Do you want "existing interest+fees" for the first 2 months (without 8% interest..)? and then "interest on principal+principal" (with 8% interest)?

Comment: @alexjo It's a typical situation where someone has not paid his/her debt, and the interest has now slowly went up (non-compound). Then the person accepts an installment plan. But you would say that the interest added before and after the plan is entered is the same :-)

Comment: There is always 8% interest from day 0. But the idea is that the debtor might first enter an installment plan (which is more like paying back a loan) in the future, and at this time, some interest has already accumulated

Comment: So let's say, at time 0 we have the debt D=Principal+Fees+Existing Interest. The interest 8% is paid on D? for example as simple interest?

Comment: @alexjo Close. The interest is only added to the Principal (using simple interest). We cannot add interest on the fees + existing interest. However, on the designed installmentplan, we have to pay back existing interest first, then fees, and then start paying back on the principal

Comment: the interest calculated on the principal is payed  also in the first 2 months but the repayment of the principal will begin on the 3rd month, right?

Comment: @alexjo In the example above, I would guess (haven't run the numbers). However, since the interest is coming every month, even in month 6 - long after the fees and initial interest have been paid - we will add a (smaller) monthly interest that will be paid first. But the "new" interest every month will be smaller and smaller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $p_k,f_k,i_k$ be the principal, the fees and the interest *right after* the payment at the $k$-th month respectively.

Also, let $x$ be the monthly installment, and let $r:=\frac{8}{100}\times\frac{1}{12}$ where we may suppose that $x$ is larger than $p_0r$.

If we have
$$i_1=i_0+p_0r-x$$
$$i_2=i_1+p_0r-x$$
$$\vdots$$
$$i_m=i_{m-1}+p_0r-x$$
where $m$ is an integer such that $$i_{m}\ge 0\quad \text{and}\quad  i_m+p_0r-x\lt 0$$
then we have
$$i_m-i_0=m(p_0r-x)$$
from which
$$0\le i_m=i_0+m(p_0r-x)\lt x-p_0r\implies 0\le\frac{i_0}{x-p_0r}-m\lt 1\implies m=\left\lfloor \frac{i_0}{x-p_0r}\right\rfloor$$
follows.

Then, we can see that 
$$p_m=p_0,\quad f_m=f_0,\quad i_m\ge 0$$
and that
$$p_{m+1}=p_0,\quad f_{m+1}=f_m+i_m+p_0r-x$$

Similarly, if we have
$$f_{m+2}=f_{m+1}+p_0r-x$$
$$\vdots$$
$$f_{n}=f_{n-1}+p_0r-x$$
where $n$ is an integer such that $$f_n\ge 0\quad \text{and}\quad f_n+p_0r-x\lt 0$$
then we have
$$f_n-f_m=i_m+(n-m)(p_0r-x)$$
from which
$$0\le f_n=f_m+i_m+(n-m)(p_0r-x)\lt x-p_0r\implies 0\le \frac{f_0+i_m}{x-p_0r}-n+m\lt 1$$
$$\implies n=m+\left\lfloor\frac{f_0+i_m}{x-p_0r}\right\rfloor=\left\lfloor\frac{f_0+i_0}{x-p_0r}\right\rfloor$$
follows.

Then, we can see that
$$p_n=p_0,\quad f_n\ge 0$$
and that
$$p_{n+1}=(r+1)p_n+f_n-x,\quad f_{n+1}=0,$$
i.e.
$$\frac{p_{n+1}}{(r+1)^{n+1}}-\frac{p_n}{(r+1)^n}=\frac{f_n}{(r+1)^{n+1}}-\frac{x}{(r+1)^{n+1}},\quad f_{n+1}=0$$

Finally, if we have
$$p_{n+2}=(r+1)p_{n+1}-x\iff \frac{p_{n+2}}{(r+1)^{n+2}}-\frac{p_{n+1}}{(r+1)^{n+1}}=-\frac{x}{(r+1)^{n+2}}$$
$$\vdots$$
$$p_{N-1}=(r+1)p_{N-2}-x\iff \frac{p_{N-1}}{(r+1)^{N-1}}-\frac{p_{N-2}}{(r+1)^{N-2}}=-\frac{x}{(r+1)^{N-1}}$$
where $N$ is an integer such that
$$p_{N-1}\gt 0\quad\text{and}\quad (r+1)p_{N-1}-x\le 0$$
then we have
$$\small\frac{p_{N-1}}{(r+1)^{N-1}}-\frac{p_{n}}{(r+1)^{n}}=\frac{f_n}{(r+1)^{n+1}}-x\sum_{j=n+1}^{N-1}\frac{1}{(r+1)^j}=\frac{f_n}{(r+1)^{n+1}}-x\cdot\frac{r+1}{r}\left(\frac{1}{(r+1)^{n+1}}-\frac{1}{(r+1)^{N}}\right)$$
from which
$$\small 0\lt \frac{p_{N-1}}{(r+1)^{N-1}}=\frac{p_{n}}{(r+1)^{n}}+\frac{f_n}{(r+1)^{n+1}}-x\cdot\frac{r+1}{r}\left(\frac{1}{(r+1)^{n+1}}-\frac{1}{(r+1)^{N}}\right)\le \frac{x}{(r+1)^N},$$
i.e.
$$0\lt (p_0r(r+1)+f_nr-x(r+1))(r+1)^{N-n-1}+x(r+1)\le rx\tag1$$
follows where
$$r=\frac{8}{100}\times\frac{1}{12},\quad n=\left\lfloor\frac{f_0+i_0}{x-p_0r}\right\rfloor,\quad f_n=f_0+i_0+\left\lfloor\frac{f_0+i_0}{x-p_0r}\right\rfloor(p_0r-x)$$

Therefore, if your input is "$N$ months", then the monthly installment $x$ is given by the smallest integer satisfying $(1)$.

---

For your example where $p_0=1000,f_0=400$ and $i_0=100$, we get, with the help of Excel, the monthly installment $x$ for each given $N$ as follows :

$$
\begin{array}{c|lcr}
\text{your input $N$ months} & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10\\
\hline
\text{monthly installment $x$} & 1507 & 756 & 506 & 381 & 306 & 256 & 220 & 193 & 172 & 155\\
\end{array}
$$
$$
\begin{array}{c|lcr}
\text{your input $N$ months} & 11 & \color{red}{12} & 13 & 14 & 15 & 16 & 17 & 18 & 19 &20&21&22\\
\hline
\text{monthly installment $x$} & 142 & \color{red}{130} & 121 & 112 & 105 & 99 & 93 & 89 & 84 & 80 & 77 & 73\\
\end{array}
$$

where $x$ is the smallest integer such that
$$0\lt \left(\frac{452}{45}+\left\lfloor\frac{500}{x-\frac{20}{3}}\right\rfloor\left(\frac{2}{45}-\frac{x}{150}\right)-\frac{151}{150}x\right)\left(\frac{151}{150}\right)^{N-1-\left\lfloor\frac{500}{x-\frac{20}{3}}\right\rfloor}+\frac{151}{150}x\le \frac{x}{150}$$

Comment: This is amazing - and it even makes sense for a math-noob like me. Thanks a lot for the very thoughtful response!

Comment: @LarsHoldgaard Have you seen the amortization schedule?? it doesn't have sense....And as you can see immediately, we must have back $1000\times(1+8\%)+400+100=1580$, but we ask only $130\times 12=1060$...the bank loose money...

Comment: @alexjo Let me rephrase. I have not digged into the details, but from this post I got to the solution :-) I have not implemented it yet, but based on the "approach here" I have made my on how to implement it.

Comment: @Lars Holdgaard can you say what is the interest payed after the first month? It' negative...and at month 12? More negative...it is impossible!!!

Comment: This answer is wrong...